# heads earns a penny, tails loses one

Tags: probability

**Problem Statement:**

The probability to get $k$ heads in $N$ flips of a fair coin follows the binomial distribution:

$$P_k = \frac{1}{2^N} { {N}\choose{k}  } $$

If I get 1 penny for each heads, and I lose 1 penny for each tails, 
the amount of money I have getting $k$ heads in $N$ flips is

$$m(k) = k - (N-k) = 2k-N.$$

Given this discrete pdf for $k$ and the function $m(k)$, what is the PDF $P_m$ of $m(k)$?

**Attempted solution**:

I know in the continuous case, I would make the cdf $c(k) = \int_0^k dk' p_k'$, I would evaluate this cdf for $m$ as $c(m) = c(k = (m+N)/2)$, and then I would differentiate the cdf $c(k)$ to get the pdf $p(m)$.

In the discrete case, I am not sure what to do. Attempting to form the CDF I am faced with a partial sum of a binomial distribution: 
$$ c_k = \sum_{l=0}^k \frac{1}{2^N}{{N}\choose{l}}$$
Do I then push on and take the difference of two of these sums to form the pdf? As in 
$$ p_m = c_{k=(m+N)/2} - c_{k = (m+N)/2-1}?$$
This seems murky. What is the factorial of a fraction?

Comment: you mean pmf, not pdf.  Also note that the $m$ that are possible must have the same parity as $N$.

Comment: Thanks. Both of these statements help a lot. I didn't actually recall that PMFs were a thing. I only had the continuum concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$M=2K-N$$

For $M$ to be a valid value with positive probability, we require $M$ and $N$ to share the same parity.

$$P_M(m) = \begin{cases} \frac1{2^N}\binom{N}{\frac{m+N}2} &, m \equiv N \pmod{2} , |m| \le \frac{N}2\\ 0 &, \text{Otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks you! I was missing the parity argument. 
Can I ask how this would differ if $M = 2K^2 - N$ for example?

Comment: you have to figure two ingredients, when does it take positive value and solve for $k$ in terms of $m$ and $N$.